# Datagridview properties form

Tags: c#, datagridview

What is the name of this form?(That is if I want to search for it, what should I search for?) and is there a way to extend it ?

[image]

Comment: It's the [Edit Columns Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171571(v=vs.100).aspx). I don't understand what you mean by "extend it" though...

Comment: I need to add some more functionality to it, for example add a new button next to the OK button

Comment: It is a dialog box that appears in the designer for editing columns. It is not a control you can use in your program and it is not possible to add buttons on it.

Comment: Can I modify the code that is executed when I click the "Edit Columns" link that appears if I clicked the top right corner of the grid?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for  your effort

Comment: Yes It's somehow possible. But the solution depends on your requirement. What's your actual requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The control on the right side is a PropertyGrid - so i guess it is filled by reflection. If you derive a custom type from DataColumn, this control should show all new properties as well. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid) is a detailed description, which attributes you should use to decorate your properties, so that a description shows up, the right editor is shown, etc.

Comment: It is a good idea, but I have something in mind that cannot be done like this. Thanks for ur effort

Comment: Instead of always saying "I have something in my mind" you might want to tell us, so we have a chance to help you, no?